# How to use BootSectorScan with MpCmdRun (Windows)

Tags: windows, anti-virus

The MpCmdRun documentation, such as it is, shows the existence of a "-BootSectorScan" option which "enables boot sector scanning" and that is "only valid for custom scan[s]".  However, I cannot find a way to actually use it or, perhaps, find any indication that it has any effect.

I've tried the following:

```
[1] MpCmdRun -Scan -ScanType 3 -BootSectorScan
[2] MpCmdRun -Scan -ScanType 1 -BootSectorScan
[3] MpCmdRun -Scan -ScanType 2 -File C:\Temp -BootSectorScan
```

[1] fails with an "invalid argument" error.
[2] and [3] run, but I cannot find any indication (in MpCmdRun.log or in event viewer) that any boot sector scanning was done.

What is the proper way, if any, of using the -BootSectorScan option, and how do I tell that it actually did anything?

Answer (score 1):

#### I cannot find a way to actually use it

```
MpCmdRun -Scan -ScanType -BootSectorScan
```

So omit the `-ScanType` argument

Sources:

- [How to use Microsoft Defender Antivirus with Command Prompt on Windows 10 | Windows Central](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-windows-defender-command-prompt-windows-10)
- [How to Run Windows Defender from Command Line - Windows Bulletin Tutorials](http://windowsbulletin.com/how-to-run-windows-defender-from-command-line/)

Comment: That is pretty much the same as my option [2] above.  The only difference is that is starts the default scan (a full scan in my case), but it certainly doesn't run a boot sector scan only, and there is no indication that adding '-bootsectorscan' changed the behavior of the scan.